# How to get the solution and prediction of nuclear ridge regression?

Tags: machine-learning

\begin{equation}
\label{eqs.1}
\tilde{y}=\sum_{m=1}^{M}\alpha_{m}\kappa(x^{(m)},\tilde{x}) (1)
\end{equation}
where $\kappa(x^{(m)},\tilde{x})$defines the similarity between data and can be chosen beforehand.The weighting$\alpha=(\alpha_{1},...,\alpha_{M})^{T}$,for instance,can be determined by minimizing the least-square loss function
\begin{equation}
\label{eqs.2}
L(\alpha)=\sum_{m=1}^{M}(\tilde{y}^{(m)}-y^{(m)})^{2}+\chi\sum_{m=1}^{M}\alpha_{m}^{2} (2)
\end{equation}
The combination of (1) and (2) is a kernel ridge regression. How to get the solution and prediction of nuclear ridge regression?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its off topic. It would be more appropriate for the Cross Validated stackexchange site